# Append Select Value to Title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append the select value for each div to its heading. How can I grab the value within each div then append it?

I want to append this on page load and not wait until a click or change takes effect. Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dqfvyvdt/2/

Markup: Repeated multiple times and each box will have a different `selected` value.

```
<div class="module">
<h3>This is a </h3>
<select name="type" class="type">
    <option selected="selected" value="car">Car</option>
    <option value="car">Bike</option>
    <option value="truck">Truck</option>
    <option value="skateboard">Skateboard</option>
    <option value="skooter">Skooter</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var title = $('.module').find('h3');
var type = $('.module').find('.type').val();

$(title).append(type);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.module').find('.type').val()` gets the value of the first `type` element, you need to find the value of each type in relation to the `h3` element.

So you need to iterate over the `h3` and find each one's `type` value and add it to its contents

Use [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
$('.module h3').append(function(i, text){
    return  $(this).next().val()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module">
    <h3>This is a </h3>
    <select name="type" class="type">
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="bike">Bike</option>
        <option value="truck">Truck</option>
        <option value="skateboard">Skateboard</option>
        <option value="skooter">Skooter</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="module">
    <h3>This is a </h3>
    <select name="type" class="type">
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="bike" selected>Bike</option>
        <option value="truck">Truck</option>
        <option value="skateboard">Skateboard</option>
        <option value="skooter">Skooter</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="module">
    <h3>This is a </h3>
    <select name="type" class="type">
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="bike">Bike</option>
        <option value="truck">Truck</option>
        <option value="skateboard">Skateboard</option>
        <option value="skooter" selected>Skooter</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

If you want to update the content of change also then

```js
$('.module .type').change(function(i, text) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prev().find('.h3-type').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module">
  <h3>This is a <span class="h3-type"></span></h3>
  <select name="type" class="type">
    <option value="car">Car</option>
    <option value="bike">Bike</option>
    <option value="truck">Truck</option>
    <option value="skateboard">Skateboard</option>
    <option value="skooter">Skooter</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="module">
  <h3>This is a <span class="h3-type"></span></h3>
  <select name="type" class="type">
    <option value="car">Car</option>
    <option value="bike" selected>Bike</option>
    <option value="truck">Truck</option>
    <option value="skateboard">Skateboard</option>
    <option value="skooter">Skooter</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="module">
  <h3>This is a <span class="h3-type"></span></h3>
  <select name="type" class="type">
    <option value="car">Car</option>
    <option value="bike">Bike</option>
    <option value="truck">Truck</option>
    <option value="skateboard">Skateboard</option>
    <option value="skooter" selected>Skooter</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Than you very much! I was unsure on how to iterate over each element. You're awesome!